# Selenium Explicit Wait for Pagination

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium to navigate pages in a scraping project. This is the HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="day_nr" value="2"/>
<div id="js-table" class="js-table table">
Day 2 of 2                
<div class="js-pager">
<input id="myCustomUrl" name="myCustomUrl" type="hidden" value="/Ranking/Rankings"/>
<div class="pagination-container">
<ul class="pagination">
   <li class=""><a class="days" id="day_1">Day 1</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a class="days" id="day_2">Day 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click to go to the next page, I need to wait a few seconds before calling the scrape function otherwise the table won't be loaded and I'll simply scrape data from the previous page. It seems to me I should be able to do this in 3 ways:

1) Using the input element `<input type="hidden" id="day_nr" value="2"/>`:

`element = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, 'day_nr'), '2'))`

2) Using the div element just below that `<div id="js-table" class="js-table table">
Day 2 of 2`:

`element = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'js-table'), 'Day 2 of 2'))`

3) Using the the list element with "active" class `<li class="active"><a class="days" id="day_2">Day 2</a></li>`:

`element = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'active'), 'Day 2'))`

All of these run without any error yet the program is still scraping the data from the first page rather than the second. Alternatively, I've created a while loop to make the program sleep until the element with the "active" class matches the correct day I intend to scrape; this works just fine but it would be a lot cleaner if I could get the explicit wait to work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the url changes after navigating to page2? if the url is incremental with your page,  you can directly call the page and scrape what you need.

Comment: Please pos your python code related how are you "clicking", there are a lot of ways to do it. Also, after each click use sleep(3) for example to wait script-driver load website

Comment: @Sureshmani the url does not change.

Comment: @Wonka 

This is the code I'm using to click:

'driver.find_element_by_link_text(day).click()'

As mentioned  in the original post, I've tried using sleep in a while loop and it works just fine. But if I understand correctly the explicit wait method should be able to replace this approach of using time.sleep().

Comment: you should include your selenium code in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this is to use wait for stale. A stale element is one that is no longer attached to the DOM of the page. For example, you'll get a stale element exception if you locate an element on the page and store it in a variable, click something that navigates to a new page or reloads the current page, and then try to interact with the variable you declared earlier.

You can use that to let you know when the page has reloaded by finding and storing an element on the page, navigate to the next page, wait for the element to go stale, and then continue the script. It would look something like this.

```
e = driver.find_element((By.ID, 'day_nr')); # grab an element from the current page
something.click() # navigate to new page
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(e)); # once e is stale, you know you are loading the new page
# now you are ready to scrape the next page
...do stuff
```

For more info, see [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) or [the apis](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.staleness_of)